# how to get version from jar file in jenkins

Tags: shell, maven, jenkins, artifactory

I created a job in jenkins with maven for my java project. My jar name is 
artifactId-version.jar and I am deploying this jar to artifactory server. I 
have 5 to 6 jar files like this which are deployed to artifact.

My build command is

```
clean install -Dversion=$BUILD_NUMBER -Denv=r -DskipITs
```

so that my jar is like example-r-23.jar and under execute shell I have written as

```
echo $BUILD_NUMBER > src/sonarCharts/latest.txt
```

and sending this file to Artifactory. I am using curl command to read the
value in latest.txt file and downloading jar file.I am downloading them from 
my code through shell script (using wget command  like wget --user  --
password  http://artifactory/example-1.0.jar).

This process repeats for every release. Once i deliver my code to production, 
i am changing this version to 2.0 and now jar file will be like example-
2.0.jar and deploying it to artifact.I need to change my script file every 
time jar version is changed.

```
<artifactId>rabbitMQHandler</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<name>rabbitMQHandler</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
```

I followed one procedure by overwriting the version with Build number and 
passing it from command line as

```
mvn clean install -Dversion=$BUILD_NUMBER --- to build
and i am sending this BUILD_NUMBER to one txt file as
echo $BUILD_NUMBER > latest.txt --- sending this to artifactory
```

and placing that file in artifactory. I am reading that txt file through shell
script using curl and i am using that number in wget command.
I feel my way of doing is not correct and is there any other way of doing it.

Comment: You should probably use the maven-deploy-plugin and the maven-release-plugin which would take care of the deployment and versioning. What is preventing you from that?

Comment: i can use them but the version that i am deploying to be noted and script file again has to be changed based on version number which i dont want to do it.

Comment: "and placing that file in artifactory. I am reading that txt file through shell
script using curl and i am using that number in wget command." what did I just read?

Comment: i have edited my question. please check

Comment: In a Jenkins Maven build you [can use](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Maven+Project+Plugin) the POM_VERSION variable out-of-the-box, so you can use it in later job steps

Comment: I am using older version of jenkins and that is not available. can u tell me the procedure of maven release or any doc.